# how to set update and delete button for every item in listview

Tags: java, android

activity_main.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     tools:context=".MainActivity">

     <ScrollView
         android:id="@+id/scroll_view"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent">

         <LinearLayout
             android:id="@+id/linearlayout1"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
             android:orientation="vertical">

             <TextView
                 android:id="@+id/tv_name1"
                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                 android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                 android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
                 android:padding="15dp"
                 android:text="Name:"
                 android:textSize="15sp" />

             <EditText
                 android:id="@+id/et_name1"
                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                 android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
                 android:hint="Enter Your Name"
                 android:padding="15dp"
                 android:textSize="15sp" />

             <TextView
                 android:id="@+id/tv_email"
                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                 android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
                 android:padding="15dp"
                 android:text="Email:"
                 android:textSize="15dp" />

             <EditText
                 android:id="@+id/et_email"
                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                 android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
                 android:hint="Enter Your Mail"
                 android:textSize="15dp" />

             <TextView
                 android:id="@+id/tv_phoneno"
                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                 android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
                android:padding="15dp"
                 android:text="Phone No:"
                 android:textSize="15dp" />

             <EditText
                 android:id="@+id/et_phoneno"
                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                 android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
                 android:hint="Enter your Contact No"
                 android:padding="15dp"
                 android:textSize="15dp" />

             <LinearLayout
                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
                 android:layout_height="match_parent"
                 android:orientation="horizontal"
                 android:padding="15dp"
                 android:weightSum="2">

                 <TextView
                     android:id="@+id/tv_dob"
                     android:layout_width="0dp"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                     android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
                     android:layout_weight="1"
                     android:text="DOB:"
                     android:textSize="15dp"

                     />

                 <Button
                     android:id="@+id/datepicker1"
                     android:layout_width="0dp"
                     android:layout_height="30dp"
                     android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="70dp"
                     android:layout_weight="1"
                     android:textSize="15dp">

                 </Button>

            </LinearLayout>

             <TextView
                 android:id="@+id/tv_qualification"
                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
                 android:layout_height="match_parent"
                 android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                 android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
                 android:padding="15dp"
                 android:text="Qualification"
                 android:textSize="15dp" />

             <EditText
                 android:id="@+id/et_qualification"
                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
                 android:hint="Enter Your Qualification"
                 android:padding="15dp"
                 android:textSize="15dp" />

             <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linearlayout2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                 android:layout_height="match_parent"
                 android:orientation="horizontal"
                 android:padding="15dp"
                 android:weightSum="2">

                 <TextView
                     android:id="@+id/tv_time"
                     android:layout_width="0dp"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                     android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
                     android:layout_weight="1"
                     android:text="Time:"
                     android:textSize="15dp"

                     />

                 <Button
                     android:id="@+id/timepicker1"
                     android:layout_width="0dp"
                   android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                     android:layout_marginRight="70dp"
                     android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:textSize="15dp">

                 </Button>

             </LinearLayout>

             <Button
                 android:id="@+id/button_save"
                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:text="Save"
                 android:layout_gravity="center"
                 android:textSize="15dp">

             </Button>
         </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>


 </RelativeLayout>
```

MainActivity

```
import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.app.TimePickerDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.icu.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import android.os.Build;
import android.support.annotation.RequiresApi;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.TimePicker;

import java.text.ParseException;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;

import static android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL;
import static android.content.Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER;
import static android.os.DropBoxManager.EXTRA_TIME;
import static android.security.KeyChain.EXTRA_NAME;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
    public static final String EXTRA_NAME = "com.example.android.persondetails.EXTRA_NAME";
    public static final String EXTRA_EMAIL = "com.example.android.persondetails.EXTRA_EMAIL";
    public static final String EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER = "com.example.android.persondetails.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER";
    public static final String EXTRA_DOB = "com.example.android.persondetails.EXTRA_DOB";
    public static final String EXTRA_QUALIFICATION = "com.example.android.persondetails.EXTRA_QUALIFICATION";
    public static final String EXTRA_TIME = "com.example.android.persondetails.EXTRA_TIME";
    Button button1, button2, button3;
    TextView textView1, textView2, textView3, textView4, textView5, textView6;
    EditText editText1, editText2, editText3, editText4;
    private int mYear, mMonth, mDay, mHour, mMinute, format;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        button3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_save);
        textView1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_name1);
        textView2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_email);
        textView3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_phoneno);
        textView4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_dob);
        textView5 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_qualification);
        textView6 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_time);
        button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.datepicker1);
        button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.timepicker1);


        button1.setOnClickListener(this);
        button2.setOnClickListener(this);
        button3.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        if (v == button1) {

            final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
            format = c.get(Calendar.AM_PM);


            DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(this,
                    new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year,
                                              int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {

                            textView4.setText(dayOfMonth + "-" + (monthOfYear + 1) + "-" + year);

                        }
                    }, mYear, mMonth, mDay);
            datePickerDialog.show();
        }
        if (v == button2) {

            final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            mHour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
            mMinute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
            format = c.get(Calendar.AM_PM);
            final TimePickerDialog timePickerDialog;
            timePickerDialog = new TimePickerDialog(this,
                    new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {

                        @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
                        @Override
                        public void onTimeSet(TimePicker timePicker, int selectedHour, int selectedMinute) {


                            String time = selectedHour + ":" + selectedMinute;

                            SimpleDateFormat fmt = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
                            Date date = null;
                            try {
                                date = fmt.parse(time);
                            } catch (ParseException e) {

                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                            SimpleDateFormat fmtOut = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm aa");

                            String formattedTime = fmtOut.format(date);

                            textView6.setText(formattedTime);
                        }
                    }, mHour, mMinute, false);
            timePickerDialog.setTitle("Select Time");
            timePickerDialog.show();
        } 


            if (v == button3) {
                EditText editText1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_name1);
                String text = editText1.getText().toString();
                EditText editText2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_email);
                String text1 = editText2.getText().toString();
                EditText editText3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_phoneno);
                String text2 = editText3.getText().toString();
                TextView textView6 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.datepicker1); 
                String text3 = textView6.getText().toString();
                EditText editText4 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_qualification); 
                String text4 = editText4.getText().toString();
                TextView textView4 = (TextView)  findViewById(R.id.timepicker1);
                String text5 = textView4.getText().toString();
                button3=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button_save);
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra(EXTRA_NAME, text);
                intent.putExtra(EXTRA_EMAIL, text1);
                intent.putExtra(EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER, text2);
                intent.putExtra(EXTRA_DOB, text3);
                intent.putExtra(EXTRA_QUALIFICATION, text4);
                intent.putExtra(EXTRA_TIME, text5);
                startActivity(intent);

            }


        }
    }
```

second_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/tv_name1"
        android:text="Name"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/tv_phoneno"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tv_name1"
        android:text="contactno"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tv_phoneno"
        android:id="@+id/tv_email"
        android:text="Email"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/tv_dob"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tv_email"
        android:text="DOB"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/tv_qualification"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tv_dob"
        android:text="Qualification"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/tv_time"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tv_qualification"
        android:text="Time"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="120dp"
        android:weightSum="2"
        >

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tv_time"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:text="Delete"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:id="@+id/delete"
            />


        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:text="Update"
            android:id="@+id/update"
            android:padding="10dp"
            />

    </LinearLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

SecondActivity.java

```
package com.example.android.persondetails;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import static java.util.Calendar.AM;

public class SecondActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private ListView lvPerson;
    private Button addBtn,dleBtn;
    private PersonListAdapter adapter;
    private List<Person> mPersonList;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.list_view);

        mPersonList = new ArrayList<Person>();

        addBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.update);
        dleBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.delete);
        lvPerson = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);



        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String text = (String) intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_NAME);
        String text1 = (String) intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER);
        String text2 = (String) intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_EMAIL);
        String text3 = (String) intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_QUALIFICATION);
        String text4 = (String) intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_DOB);
        String text5 = (String) intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_TIME);


        Log.d("PersonDetails", text + " " + text1 + "" + text2 + "" + text3 + "" + text4 + "" + text5);
        mPersonList.add(0,new Person(text,text1,text2,text3,text4,text5));
        addMethod();
        setAdapter();

    }

    private void addMethod() {

        mPersonList.add(1,new Person("Narendra", "83330072", "narendraprasad616@gmail.com", "btech", "14 / 06 / 1996", "5-30 AM"));
        mPersonList.add(2,new Person("Banu", "715452", "naredra@gmail.com", "btech", "14 / 06 / 1996", "5-45 AM"));
        mPersonList.add(3,new Person("Kalyan", "83330072", "narendraprad616@gmail.com", "btech", "14 / 06 / 1998", "5-30 AM"));
        mPersonList.add(4,new Person("Teja", "8775564", "narendraprasa16@gmail.com", "btech", "14 / 06 / 1990", "5-30 AM"));
        mPersonList.add(5,new Person("Manu", "86423", "narendraprad616@gmail.com", "btech", "14 / 06 / 1996", "5-30 AM"));

    }


    private void setAdapter() {
        adapter = new PersonListAdapter(SecondActivity.this, mPersonList);
        lvPerson.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

how to set dailog to update button and one dailog should need to open it should be in editing what we had like in main activityxml after clicking delete it should be deleted,update means open dailog and reedit and update

> PersonListAdapter.java

```
package com.example.android.persondetails;


import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Build;
import android.support.annotation.RequiresApi;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.List;

public class PersonListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context mContext;
    private List<Person> mPersonList;

    PersonListAdapter(Context mContext, List<Person> mPersonList) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.mPersonList = mPersonList;
    }



    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mPersonList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return mPersonList.get(position);
    }


    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.P)
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.second_layout, parent, false);
            holder.tv_name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_name1);
            holder.tv_contact = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_phoneno);
            holder.tv_email=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_email);
            holder.tv_dob=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_dob);
            holder.tv_qualification=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_qualification);
            holder.tv_time=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_time);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        holder.tv_name.setText(mPersonList.get(position).getName());
        holder.tv_contact.setText(mPersonList.get(position).getContactno());
        holder.tv_email.setText(mPersonList.get(position).getEmail());
        holder.tv_dob.setText(mPersonList.get(position).getDatepicker());
        holder.tv_qualification.setText(mPersonList.get(position).getQualification());
        holder.tv_time.setText(mPersonList.get(position).getTimepicker());
        return convertView;

    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }


    class ViewHolder {
        TextView tv_name;
        TextView tv_email;
        TextView tv_contact;
        TextView tv_dob;
        TextView tv_qualification;
        TextView tv_time;

    }

}
```

Person.java

```
package com.example.android.persondetails;

public class Person {
    private String name;
    private String contactno;
    private String email;
    private String qualification;
    private String datepicker;
    private String timepicker;



    public Person(String name, String contactno, String email, String qualification, String datepicker, String timepicker) {
        this.name = name;
        this.contactno = contactno;
        this.qualification=qualification;
        this.datepicker=datepicker;
        this.email=email;
        this.timepicker=timepicker;


    }

    public String getName() {
        return name == null ? "" : name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }


    public String  getContactno() {
        return contactno;
    }

    public void  setContactno(String contactno){
        this.contactno=contactno;
    }
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public String getQualification() {
        return qualification;
    }

    public String getDatepicker() {
        return datepicker;
    }

    public String getTimepicker() {
        return timepicker;
    }
}
```

list_view.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Person">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </ListView>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.android.persondetails">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        >
        <activity android:name=".SecondActivity">
    </activity>
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Finally i need whatever we are giving details of person in first screen it should be added into the top of the list view and defalut person values needed to be stored under new persondetails,every item of listview consists of update and delete button delete means,it should be deleted from the list ,update means open dailog and re-edit it and save the remoduled data into respective positions.

Comment: WHAT DO YOU WANT TO ACHIEVE, ACTUALLY

Comment: it's a task given by my senior@Lakhwinder Singh help me out

Comment: what is the task basically

Comment: two screens ,first screen with name,email,phoneno,datepicker,timepicker,qualification these all are in scrollable below one save button after clicking save button these data should be added to next screen of list view (contains 5defalut person details)at top of listview,every item in list view contains delete and update button,delete means delete that item from the listview,update means one custom dailog should open and re-edit and updated @ Lakhwinder Singh

Comment: @ Lakhwinder Singh name and phone ,email all should be validated

Comment: thanks,please kindly refer me which books shall i prefer to study@Zun

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add two buttons such as Update and Delete in the list item's layout. So the list holder class will look like:

```
class ViewHolder {
    TextView tv_name;
    TextView tv_email;
    TextView tv_contact;
    TextView tv_dob;
    TextView tv_qualification;
    TextView tv_time;
    Button btn_update; //Update for item
    Button btn_delete; //Delete an item.
}
```

Once you have done this then do the following in adapter's getView() method. Notice the comments carefully to understand the implementational logic further.

```
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.second_layout, parent, false);
        holder.tv_name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_name1);
        holder.tv_contact = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_phoneno);
        holder.tv_email=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_email);
        holder.tv_dob=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_dob);
        holder.tv_qualification=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_qualification);
        holder.tv_time=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_time);

        //bind holder.btn_update and holder.btn_delete here

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    holder.tv_name.setText(mPersonList.get(position).getName());
    holder.tv_contact.setText(mPersonList.get(position).getContactno());
    holder.tv_email.setText(mPersonList.get(position).getEmail());
    holder.tv_dob.setText(mPersonList.get(position).getDatepicker());
    holder.tv_qualification.setText(mPersonList.get(position).getQualification());
    holder.tv_time.setText(mPersonList.get(position).getTimepicker());

    holder.btn_update.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //Call your dialog to update and pass "mPersonList.get(position)" model so that data in the model will be updated.
            //Once update is done call refreshList() from the confirmation dialog button.
        }
    });

    holder.btn_delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mPersonList.remove(position);
            refreshList();
        }
    });

    return convertView;

}

private void refreshList() {
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

One suggestion, try to avoid using variables like button1, button2, editText1, textView1 like school students. Instead of these, use a proper and meaningful name for the variables.

Comment: thank you so much,helped me a lot....how to call the dailog  to update....that dailog class where shall i extend that class(i mean adapter or need to create another dailog class)

Comment: I want to open the custom dailog showing details like activity_main.xml and shall be show like edit text and text view like in activitymain.xml.need to update in which item i have clicked update pleasehelpme@Hari N jha

Comment: @RobinHood help me

Comment: You need to call dialog from adapter from onClick() of update button. By doing simpe Google, you will get help for creating dialog box with edittext.

Answer (score 0):

you can put your logic in getView() method with button click listener.